# Cherry picking commit in git: is large file data duplicated?

Tags: git, diskspace, git-cherry-pick

I understand that if you cherry pick a commit in git, it creates a new copy of the commit (with new SHA etc).

But internally, if there is a large binary file, is the data duplicated, causing the repo to bloat? Or is it smart enough to understand that it's the same blob?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git *is* smart enough to keep using the same object and reference it in the new created commit from your cherry-pick. (Although I somewhat understand your worries about a duplicate copy, since the commit itself isn't just duplicated but recreated.)

When the file will actually change, **then** you'll have a new object created, thus increasing the repo.

Answer (score 4):

From a user's point of view, it's natural to think of a commit as "containing" files, but internally, it is more accurate to say that a commit "refers to" files.

At its base, git is a content-indexed object store: there are a bunch of objects, all identified uniquely by their SHA1 hash. On top of this store, objects are given meaning to represent the components of a version control system.

There is [a good introduction to this on the Git website](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects).

So when you commit a file, several objects are stored:

- A "blob" object containing the file's contents, with no metadata
- A "tree" object containing the directory listing, with a name and metadata for each file, and the SHA1 hash of its current content
- A "commit" object representing the commit, including the commit message, the time of the commit, the SHA1 hashes of the parent commit(s), and the SHA1 hash of the directory listing to use

The SHA1 you normally see is the SHA1 of this commit object - knowing that is enough for git to find the full commit info, and from there find the directory listing, and from there the file content.

When you cherry-pick a commit, git will need to create:

- A new commit object, with a new time, parent commit(s), etc
- Possibly a new tree object, as the result of merging the cherry-picked changes will probably result in some files being different
- New blob objects *for any file that has new contents*; if the large file has identical content to any previous state, it will by definition have the same SHA1 hash, so will not be stored again

In a sense, git is *not* being "smart" here - it doesn't care *why* an object might be duplicated, it just stores one object for every SHA1 hash, and if it finds an object already exists with that hash, assumes they are the same thing. The ability for multiple, possibly unrelated, commits to refer to the same file contents just falls out as a convenient side-effect of this storage system.